# nginx + php + owncloud index.php/apps/files rewritten

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, owncloud

Currently I mess up with nginx a lot.

I do move an ownCloud from an Hosting Solution to an own VPS, based on nginx.

After some problems now it's running well, but there is one thing I can't dive in.

> calling: owncloud.domain.tld :: OK clicking the "files-icon", wich
>   actually redirects to the current view, but URL should change to:
>   owncloud.domain.tld/index.php/apps/files :: FAILS

Becaus nginx (or something between) converts "`index.php/apps/files`" to "`index.php/apps/index.php`"... whats up there? How can I fix this?
Calling "`index.php/apps/gallery`" and others even works fine!

The nginx file:

```
# cloud.xyz.de

server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name cloud.xyz.de;

    server_tokens off;
    root /nowhere;

    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
  listen *:443;
  server_name cloud.xyz.de;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/cloud_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/cloud_error.log;

  client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size
  fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

  rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/apps/calendar/caldav.php /remote.php/caldav/ last; # this was injected after some reading in the WWW
  rewrite ^/apps/contacts/carddav.php /remote.php/carddav/ last; # this was injected after some reading in the WWW
  rewrite ^/apps/([^/]*)/(.*\.(css|php))$ /index.php?app=$1&getfile=$2 last; # this was injected after some reading in the WWW
  rewrite ^/remote/(.*) /remote.php last; # this was injected after some reading in the WWW

  root /var/www/cloud.xyz.de;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
  error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/xyz_de.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/xyz_de.key;
  ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers AES:HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

    rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
  }

  location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
    try_files $1 = 404;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
#    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # this was injected after some reading in the WWW
    fastcgi_index index.php; # this was injected after some reading in the WWW
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
    expires 30d;
    # Optional: Don't log access to assets
    access_log off;
  }
}
```

This isn't such an big thing. But I'm searching now for hours and don't know where to search anymore.

Comment: have you seen the official owncloud/nginx documentation: http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_others.html

Comment: Hey RandolphCarter, yes I did. Severall times. Since some weeks its working now, forgot to WDIT my post.. Don't now whats different now ^^ Thanks for your Reply.